# How do US intercity bus companies relate to each other?

Tags: usa, buses, greyhound

When I book a journey via [Greyhound Lines](http://www.greyhound.com/) or [Jefferson Lines](http://www.jeffersonlines.com/), the offers include journeys by other bus companies, such as [Burlington Trailways](http://www.burlingtontrailways.com) or [Black Hills Stage Lines](http://blackhillsstagelines.com/).
This goes both ways; booking via [Black Hills Stage Lines](http://blackhillsstagelines.com/) also shows trips by *Greyhound Lines*.
The interfaces used by the website search engines appear very similar.

Is there some cooperation of bus companies so that they sell each others tickets?

If yes, who are included?  If no, according to what system do I get listings from company Y on the website from company X?

Does it matter where I book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your main question:  They Cooperate.

For the reasons one would need to look at the other major Intercity Bus Transit systems the [Trailways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailways_Transportation_System).  Greyhound in 1987 acquired the major participant in the [Trailways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailways_Transportation_System) cooperative and established themselves as near monopoly.

I guess that in order to avoid being branded a monopoly and potentially be broken up they established cooperative ticketing mechanisms with other providers like the ones in [Trailways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailways_Transportation_System) system.

So long story short.  Any bus company participating in the Trailways system you will be able to book through [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.com) or their own booking systems, though some don't provide ability to [buy such tickets online](http://www.martztrailways.com).

You may not be able to buy through Greyhound tickets on regional transportation lines like [NJ Transit](http://www.njtransit.com) and its affiliates, as well as [Coach Lines](http://www.coachusa.com/)